# Error when starting Node Application - MEAN Stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I have started to create a Node js application using MEAN Stack so i have followed the steps in the following URL to intialize a node js Application using MEAN. 
[Link](http://meanjs.org/docs.html#getting-started)

When i provide GRUNT or Started the Node js Application in Terminal, I am getting the following error.

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
    Error: ENOENT, open '/home/vigneshmoha/Documents/node/branding/public/system/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

npm version 1.4.15

Node js version v0.10.28

MongoDB version v2.6.1

I haven't changed anything else. Am i missing anything?

Comment: path probably doesn't exist

Comment: Yea, path doesn't exist. There is no 'lib' folder inside the public->system folder. How do i resolve this with adding the folders and files manually? Anyway i am not going to using Bootstrap Library.

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure about this but try installing bower with the command..

```
npm install -g bower
```

and then `sudo bower install --allow -root`
Now check if the files are created

Comment: thanks, wierd that following the instructions as they have it doesn't work on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04, but after running these commands, and then passing ownership back to me, or the user that will be running the server, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
npm cache clean 
npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the exact same problem (on Mac OS X 10.9). Running *npm install* without sudo fixed it. Seems like bower is causing some troubles when used with sudo.

Answer (score 1):

This error might be also due to errors in your Nodejs application. Fix the errors. You might also need to install bower:
npm install -g bower . tested on windows 10 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue., tried to delete node_modules, did npm install., but the scenario remained same.

On restarting the system, it seems to be back to normal.